# Using two business cards in the same composer rest server configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I did the tutorial to deploy to a multi org fabric network and it worked successfully .

Now i have two admin cards - **alice@trade-network , bob@trade-network**

and two identities/cards issued by them - **jdoe@trade-network , dlowe@trade-network**

Now i have given access control rules stating that jdoe (trader1-org1) and dlowe(trader2-org2) **can only view their own records**

Thus when i connect to their respective business cards i am able to view only their records . Now i can start two rest servers each  (2 ports) for jdoe and dlowe which enables view of their records only through their rest api endpoints .

Now i know for a fact i can start another rest server for alice or bob who are admins so they can view all the records (jdoe's and dlowe's) 
But i dont want to do it that way . That is start a third rest server .

Is there any other way to achieve this . To get all the records in all cards ! 
Is there a way to start a rest server with two card instances or something like that .

Suggestions ??  Thanks~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cool that you've been playing around with possibilities firstly.

The simple answer is to start a single REST server in multi-user mode, which enables wallets. See more here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-multiuser with an example of using Wallets (into which business network cards are stored). You can persist the wallet store to disk as described here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

Then `jdoe, dlow, alice and bob`  - as participants of the business network (each with their own business network card governed by whatever ACL rules are in place) - can interact using a browser client (REST API client) as the different participants (and therefore see different results as per your ACL rules).

There is an example of this in the [Google OAUTH2 tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) which shows how you switch identities, import a user's business network card / set it as default in the REST API, so that its using a specific blockchain identity / participant to perform activities on the business network (see specifically 'Step Eleven' onwards).

Comment: All of this by starting a single rest server is it ? sounds good . Will give it a go ! Thanks .So for switching identities we need to provide the authentication ?

Comment: yes correct, because you are running in `multi-user` mode - you will need to enable authentication (ie use a PassportJS authentication strategy - described in the first link I sent).