# Multiple chaincodes/scripts in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am studying **Hyperledger composer** and trying out various samples .

The example i am trying out is similar to [Using two business cards in the same composer rest server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836451/using-two-business-cards-in-the-same-composer-rest-server-configuration)

There is a single script file in the business network (**trade-network.bna**) that has the business logic , and hence is the chaincode/smart contract for adding / updating asset in the ledger.

Also the fabric network on top of which composer runs on has the GO lang chaincode .

Is there a way to run multiple scripts in hyperledger composer or a way to run multiple chaincodes . Any workarounds or suggestions

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i think is not possible to use a single .bna to create different chaincodes. The ratio between chaincode and business network archives (bna) is one to one. If you want to run different chaincodes you must install different .bna to your peers.

Comment: looks like that is the only way . A different bna . Otherwise directly install Go chaincode on the peer itself directly from fabric

Answer (score 0):

We can add another BNA and then do this - https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network