# Composer rest server multi user error clarification

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am trying out Composer rest server multiuser mode -

This is my setup:

- I have 3 NetworkAdmin users alice,bob and charles
- Through these admins i have issued identities to jdoe,dave (for alice
  and bob) each with their ACLs as participants .
- So **alice** is an admin with participant/identity - **jdoe**

  **bob** is an admin with a participant/identity - **dave**

  **charles** is an admin .
- The setup is similar to [Using two business cards in the same composer rest server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836451/using-two-business-cards-in-the-same-composer-rest-server-configuration)

-> I start the rest server for alice with multiuser mode enabled and add identity jdoe to its wallet . Now when i try to do a rest operation it says :

```
"message": "Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":20,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]"
```

-> Same for bob - if i try to add dave it gives the same error .

-> Also if i try to add identities dave and jdoe to charles` wallet it gives same error

## However the multiuser mode works in the following scenario

1) Through **alice** who is an admin i create a participant '**restadmin**' who is also a NetworkAdmin

```
composer participant add -c alice@trade-network -d '{"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin", "participantId":"restadmin"}'
composer identity issue -c alice@trade-network -f cards/restadmin.card -u restadmin -a "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#restadmin"

composer card import -f  cards/restadmin.card
composer network ping -c restadmin@trade-network
```

2) Now i create another participant **Jam** through **alice**

```
composer participant add -c alice@trade-network -d '{"$class":"org.example.trading.Trader","tradeId":"trader4", "RepfirstName":"Jam","ReplastName":"J"}'

composer identity issue -c alice@trade-network -f cards/jam.card -u jam -a "resource:org.cdc.MortalityCard.State#state4-ny"

composer card import -f cards/jam.card


composer card export -f cards/jam_exp.card -c jam@trade-network ; rm cards/jam.card
```

3)Now it works , This is hilarious i have no idea why it didnt work i nthe previous scenario ., now it works only if the identity is set as **Jam** as default . it doesnt work with jdoe or dave

No idea why . suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the difference is in scenario 2, you've exported the cards with credentials (cert/key) - in scenario 1 they're trying to enrol again (because you've only got the secret in the card, no credentials set).

When the Identity is issued by the Fabric Certificate of Authority (CA) server  a one-time secret is created (ie part of the Card that is created). When the card is *used* (eg connect or ping the business network using the card) for the first time, the secret is exchanged for Certificates/Keys (credentials) and then the one-time secret is invalidated. for scenario 1, you need to export it (eg via the Command line with composer card export -c jdoe@ -f jdoe-plus-cert.card ) and then import that new .card file in the REST API wallet (eg /Import endpoint) and then it would also work for you in the REST API.

Comment: looks like that is the problem . ill try out and let you know . Thanks

Comment: but in scenario 2 - even if i export jdoe as jdoe_exp.card and import , it doesnt work . why is that ? it works with jam though .

Comment: also in the first scenario i request cards for alice as admin by using commands :
"composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@trade-network-u admin -s adminpw -d alice"  
and then create a card for alice by using 

"composer card create -p composer/org1/trade-network-org1.json -u alice -n trade-network -c cards/alice/admin-pub.pem -k cards/alice/admin-priv.pem -f cards/alice/alice@trade-network.card"

"composer card import -f cards/alice/alice@trade-network.card"

"composer network ping -c alice@trade-network"

Comment: Its working ! THANKS A LOT . Exporting and importing new the new card did the trick !